# Importing two different classes with same name from different packages

Tags: java

I imported class `Logger` from package `java.util.logging` by using `import java.util.logging.Logger`. In addition to that, as per requirement I need to import user created class from some other package. But the problem is, that class name also `Logger`[Created in user defined package]. I don't have permissions to change the name of that user defined class and package. Both classes have the static methods.

So I need to import two both classes, then what is feasible solution for this?

Comment: use the full package name. like "com.abc.xxx.Logger"

Answer (score 5):

call the full class name, i.e. `package.class`.
for instance, if you would create some class named `File`, you could still use `java.io.File` without importing it.
imports only lets you use the shorter name. a class full name is prepended by it's package name

in your case, you have: `some.user.package.Logger`, so you could use it exactly like that.

```
some.user.package.Logger userLogger = new some.user.package.Logger();
java.util.logging.Logger realLogger = java.util.logging.Logger.getAnonymousLogger(); //or whatever...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the full path.

```
Logger logger = new Logger();
com.abc.Logger yourLogger = new com.abc.Logger();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using one of the classes with same name but different package,

use fully qualified class name like :

```
java.util.logging.Logger logger;
mypackage.Logger myLogger;
```

Answer (score 0):

best way is to use fully qualified class names where you are using them in the class, without importing anything